# Add term to taxonomy programatically

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a 1000+ terms I need to add to a taxonomy called `county`. I am trying to use this function 
[wp_insert_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term#Hooks_Used) but the term is not being added to the database. I am running this code inside `function.php` as a test before looping over each unique term. Should I be using a specific hook?

```
wp_insert_term(
  'Maricopa',
  'county',
  array(
    'description'=> 'Maricopa',
    'slug' => 'maricopa'
  )
);
```

Also curious of other ways of adding multiple terms at once. Is there a REST API option for doing this?

**EDIT**

Tried using this hook but same result the term was not added to the 'county' taxonomy.

```
function add_county_terms() {
  wp_insert_term( 'Maricopa', 'county', array(
    'slug' => 'maricopa',
  ));
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'add_county_terms' );
```

Comment: Does it add no terms? Or only some of them? Keep in mind that adding 1000 of anything will be slow, it's highly unlikely it will be finished before the PHP execution time limit kicks in and your request is stopped in its tracks. This is the kind of thing a WP CLI command is great at, or doing it bit by bit with the REST API

Comment: As an aside, do you have 1000 `wp_insert_term` calls in your `functions.php`? How big is that file?

Comment: For now only trying to add a single term 'Maricopa'. The plan is if I am able to add the one correctly run a foreach on my 'Counties' array using 'wp_insert_term' for each term in the loop.

Comment: Your taxonomy isn't registered until `init`, so that code definitely needs to run later than when the file is loaded.

Comment: Does it return any error?

Comment: No errors when running the code. @Milo I tried using the 'wp_loaded' hook to set this up with but still didn't work for me, see edited question.

Comment: @Benjamin use `init` as is standard practice, or better yet, a WP CLI command. What you're trying to do won't work at that scale the way you're building it anyway even if you get this 1 example working, there isn't enough time to add all 1000 terms. This could be answered yes, but you'd still have the problem that what you asked and what you're trying to do are not the same thing. Ask instead how to bulk add terms and adjust the question accordingly, using what you're currently doing as an example, rather than asking how to fix a solution

Comment: I used the plugin WP All Import and handled the task perfectly.